# rsync doesn't preserve directory ownership even with -a

Tags: files, permissions, users, rsync

I use this rsync invocation to backup my home directory:

```
rsync -aARrx --info= --force --delete --info=progress2 -F "$USER_HOME" "$BACKUP_MNTPOINT"
```

rsync man page says that -a implies -g and -o (among other switches), which should preserve ownership. However I've noticed that if a directory does not exist under `$BACKUP_MNTPOINT/$USER_HOME`, it is created with root:root ownership instead of the correct one. (This only happens with directories right under `$BACKUP_MNTPOINT/$USER_HOME`). Why is that?

`$BACKUP_MNTPOINT` is a localy mounted drive. `$BACKUP_MNTPOINT/$USER_HOME` does have the right ownership and permissions. Neither `$USER_HOME` nor `$BACKUP_MNTPOINT` end with a slash.

Both the source and the target filesystems are XFS and running `mkdir $BACKUP_MNTPOINT/$USER_HOME` creates a directory with the expected ownership.

Comment: What filesystem is `$BACKUP_MNTPOINT` and with what options is it mounted? Does this happen only for the parent (`$BACKUP_MNTPOINT/$USER_HOME`) directory or for all directories created? Do `$BACKUP_MNTPOINT` and `$USER_HOME` end with a `/`?

Comment: I use XFS for both `/home` and the backup drive. So far I think it only happened for the parent directories. Neither `$BACKUP_MNTPOINT` nor `$USER_HOME` end with a slash.
**EDIT:** I can confirm now it only happens to the directories right below `$BACKUP_MNTPOINT/$USER_HOME`

Comment: So `$BACKUP_MNTPOINT/$USER_HOME` has the right permissions but any subdirectories do not? Please [edit] your question and add these details. Also, clarify whether `mkdir $BACKUP_MNTPOINT/$USER_HOME/foo` creates a directory owned by your user if you do it manually.

Comment: Yes, `mkdir $BACKUP_MNTPOINT/$USER_HOME/foo` creates a directory with the user's ownership.

Comment: Would be really nice to see relevant information from `strace` (as specified in a pseudo answer).

Comment: Ok, the next time I do backup I'll try to gather some info.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had a similar problem when using `rsync` to backup my system to my server. I used:

```
rsync -aAXSHPr \
-e ssh \
--rsync-path="sudo /usr/bin/rsync/" \
--numeric-ids \
--delete \
--progress \
--exclude-from="/path/to/file/that/lists/excluded/folders.txt" \
--include-from="/path/to/file/that/lists/included/folders.txt" \
/ USER@SERVER:/path/to/folder/where/backup/should/go/
```

The solution is that there is not really a problem. I suspect that you aborted the `rsync` process once you saw that it creates folders with wrong permissions set. The crux is that `rsync` only sets the permissions of a parent-folder once it is done syncing all subfolders and files of it.

Comment: Wow, that didn't occur to me at all, nicely spotted, thanks.

Comment: rsync-path would be "sudo /usr/bin/rsync" rather than "sudo /usr/bin/rsync/", right?

Comment: Also rsync needs to be run as root in order to preserve ownership.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps run rsync via strace/truss and see if you get an error back from the chown() syscall, and also to confirm that chown() has the correct path and UID/GID.

Comment: A good comment but not an answer.